# How to start AbiWord with full screen?

Tags: x11

2.8.2-2ubuntu1.1

How can I set Abiword to always start with full screen?

Comment: There may be a way to do this from your window manager. Some WM can be configured to always start a particular application full-screen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `geometry` argument.

`$ abiword --geometry=[YOUR_SCREEN_WIDTH]x[YOUR_SCREEN_HEIGHT]`